# Modal not toggling on

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have created a project contains 3 modals 'contact', 'log in' and register'. They were at one time all functioning correctly. I checked the following: bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js, and jQuery links. jQuery and JS links are at the bottom of the html and prior to the  tag. All links looked OK. Tried to correct this condition for several hours prior to posting this question.
It seems as if the jQuery or .js links are not being linked, however as I said they look fine.

One other important thing is that the modal date is being shown to the bottom left and beneath the page container.

Sorry I can't post images however, I'm informed that I need a reputation of at least 10 to post images. I just recently joined.

I know it's difficult to troubleshoot when all the info is not there, Please can someone please help. I'm sure it's something simple that

Comment: Can you give as the code!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my trick for managing modals as the same thing has happened to me. First remove the default id="#myModal" from bootstrap's example and use a class as follows: For 3 modals you would use 3 times. My thought is that you may have conflicting ID's hence your code breaks.  You can see an example of multiple modals in use using this pattern at [this example](http://triplewww.com/cm/separation/separation.html)

```
   <div class="modal fade modal1"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
   labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  //rest of modal code

   </div>

   <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal1">

   <div class="modal fade modal2"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
   labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

   //rest of modal code

   </div>

   <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal2">

  <div class="modal fade modal3"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
  labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

 //rest of modal code

 </div>
```